# Sort dataframe with multilevel column index in increasing order based on 2nd index

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe with a multilevel column index:

'A'/(0,1], 'A'/(1,2], 'A'/(10,11], 'A'/(11,12], 'A'/(12,13], ..., 'A'/(19,20], 'A'/(2,3], 'A'/(20,21], ....

and then the same with 'L' instead of 'A'.

> I want a different sorting order. Currently, the intervals are sorted alphanumerically. I want to sort them in increasing fashion, i.e.:
>
> 'A'/(0,1], 'A'/(1,2], 'A'/(2,3], 'A'/(3,4], ....., 'L'/(0,1], 'L'/(1,2], 'L'/(2,3], 'L'/(3,4]

How can I achieve that?

What I tried so far (but what didn't work):

```
def custom_sort_key(index):
    type_value = index[0]
    interval = index[1]
    lower_bound = interval(interval.split(',')[0].strip('('))

    type_value_numeric = 0 if type_value == "A" else 1

    return (type_value_numeric, lower_bound)

df_sorted = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1, key=lambda x: x.map(custom_sort_key))
```